# The accessToken I am getting from Auth0/NextJs not working on Routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, access-token, auth0

I am using `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` for my nextJs login.

This is my /[auth0].js code:

```
import { handleAuth, handleLogin } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

  export default handleAuth({
  login: handleLogin({
    authorizationParams: {
      audience: process.env.AUDIENCE, 
    }
  })
});
```

After login, I am calling the getAccessToken() and what I get as token doesn't work with my endpoint. But when I copy test accessToken from auth0 dashboard, it will work.

```
import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired, getSession } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";


export default withApiAuthRequired(async function users(req, res) {
  try {
    const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res);
    const {user} = await getSession(req, res);
    console.log("with access token …", accessToken);
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/auth", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      method: "GET",
```

The response I always get is 401, Unathorized.

What am I doing wrong?